# Setting up Redux with React Native function undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-redux

I think I'm close with setting up React Redux for my React native app. I currently have this set up.

Here I define the action that I want to call.

```js
/* actions/mapActions.js */

export const setMarker = selectedMarker => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_MARKER',
    selectedMarker
  }
}
```

Here I define the container for the component that I want to use the store in.

```js
//containers/mapContainers.js

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setMarker } from './actions/mapActions'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    selectedMarker: state.marker
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    markerClick: (marker) => {
      dispatch(setMarker(marker))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

Here I combine the reducers as I've seen in a tutorial I've been following.

```js
//reducers/index.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import mapReducer from './mapReducer'

const dabApp = combineReducers({
  mapReducer
})

export default dabApp
```

Here I define the reducer for the component.

```js
//reducers/mapReducers.js

const mapReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_MARKER':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          marker: action.marker
        }
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default mapReducer
```

Main entry point to the application.

```js
//App.js

// other imports here
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import snapApp from './reducers';

let store = createStore(dabApp);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
            {Platform.OS === 'android' &&
              <View style={styles.statusBarUnderlay} />}
              <RootNavigation />
          </View>
        </Provider>
      );
  }



}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//Styles.
});
```

Here I define the component.

```js
//Standard react imports.

import { MapView } from 'expo';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    //Set states.
  };
}


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
         //MapView info
      >
      {this.state.markers.map((marker) =>
          <MapView.Marker
            key={marker.id}
            coordinate={marker.coordinate}
            onPress={() => {this.props.markerClick(marker); this.props.navigation.navigate('Information');}}>
            </MapView.Marker>
        )}
      </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  //Styles.
});
```

The error I get is that the function 'markerClick' is undefined in the Map.Marker onPress prop. I have followed the tutorial religiously and can't find the solution to this.

The tutorial that I was following was this one on the official redux site. http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Unfortunately, Harry's answer hasn't solved the issue.

I console.log(this.props) and I get this:

Still is undefined. When I console.log(this.props") I get:

```js
        Object {
          "navigation": Object {
          "dispatch": [Function anonymous],
          "goBack": [Function goBack],
          "navigate": [Function navigate],
          "setParams": [Function setParams],
          "state": Object {
            "key": "Home",
            "routeName": "Home",
          },
        },
        "screenProps": undefined,
        "selectedMarker": [Function dispatch],
        "type": "SET_MARKER",
      }
```

so I don't even see the function on my props.

As you can see, the function is not defined on this.props.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're making more steps than needed.

Try something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MapView } from 'expo';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { setMarker } from './actions/mapActions'


class HomeScreen extends Component {
  onPress(marker) {
    this.props.setMarker(marker);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Information');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <MapView>
           {this.state.markers.map((marker) => (
             <MapView.Marker
               key={marker.id}
               coordinate={marker.coordinate}
               onPress={() => { this.onPress(marker); }}
             />
           )
        )}
      </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  //Styles.
});

export default connect(null, setMarker)(HomeScreen);
```

You don't need to define a function that then dispatches an action, you can just connect the action to the component. 
It's also much nicer to just have everything in the same file instead of having a separate mapContainers.js

Comment: Ok cool! Thank you will give this a go! I agree with you, but was just trying to follow the tutorial :)

Comment: Btw, if you're looking for places to learn, I think this is by far the best course on react native out there:
https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/learn/v4/

it's not free, but you can get it for like 10$ during Udemy's special deal days.

Comment: I will checkmark the answer once I've checked it at home!